# Function pointer initialization with function declaration - is it possible?

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization, declaration

Is it possible to initialize function pointer with function declaration in C++? I mean, something like this:

```
void (*pointer)(void) = &( void function(void) );
```

or this:

```
void (*pointer)(void) = void function(void);
```

Comment: My recommendation is that you stop using explicit function pointers. Either use `auto` for automatic type-deduction, or if you need to save or pass the "function" around use [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost possible, you just have to reverse the order: declare the function first, and then initialise the pointer with its address:

```
void function(), (*pointer)() = &function;
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9896e529a04114f)

However, I consider this ugly, unreadable code, and would never suggest actually using it. So, my answer is: "It's possible, but should never be done." <sub>(I can imagine it being excusable in certain situations involving macros, but that's about it).</sub>

Comment: Generally agree.   Except that it is rarely excusable in C++ to use macros, let alone use such a construct in one.

Comment: @Peter Until we get metaclasses in C++, macros will have their uses for boilerplate elimination and code generation. I fully agree they should be used sparingly, but nevertheless cosider them a legitimate tool.

Comment: I did say "rarely", not "never"

Answer (score 1):

No, as any variable in C++ (including function pointers) has to be initialized with an *expression*, and a function declaration is not an expression.

You might want to use a captureless lambda expression instead:

```
void (*pointer)() = []{ std::cout << "hello world\n"; };
```

Answer (score 0):

No, since a pointer - including a function pointer - must be initialised using an expression.   A function declaration is not an expression.

However, an expression can be composed using previously declared functions (or variables) in the compilation unit (aka source file)

```
void function();     //  declare the function, defined elsewhere

void (*pointer)() = function;   //  function name in an expression is converted to a function pointer
```

It is possible (not recommended for readability purposes) to combine the two in one declaration of multiple variables.

```
void function(), (*pointer)() = function;
```

Answer (score 0):

An initializer may not be a declaration. It does not make sense. You already specified the type of the pointer when you declared it.

If you declare a pointer and want to initialize it when you have to assign it some value.

Here is a demonstrative program. It uses an array of function pointers (to be more interesting).

```
#include <iostream>

void f1()
{
    std::cout << "Hello ";
}

void f2()
{
    std::cout << "Roman Kwaśniewski";
}

void f3()
{
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    void ( *fp[] )() = { f1, f2, f3 };

    for ( auto &func : fp ) func();
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello Roman Kwaśniewski
```

Pay attention to that you need not to specify for example &f2 as initializer because a function designator is implicitly converted to pointer.

Though for example this initialization is also correct

```
    void ( *fp[] )() = { f1, %f2, f3 };
```

and is equivalent to the previous one.